# Error with no build/config/win/visual_studio_version.gni:27:7 on pdfium build

Tags: windows, codeblocks, wxwidgets, pdfium

After gn args out\debug i have the error

> ERROR at //build/config/win/visual_studio_version.gni:27:7: Script
> returned non-zero exit code.
> exec_script("../../vs_toolchain.py", [ "get_toolchain_dir" ], "scope")

I remove Visual Studio, and i want to build pdfium with clang-cl.
I don’t know how, without MSVS in my pc.
The target of all this is to be able build my linux project with wxWidgets, CodeBlocks and pdfium in windows with clang-cl.
Thank you.
Jim

Comment: I believe that this is a non-trivial. AFAIR, this can be built only with MSVC. Or you can try to get a precompiled binaries from their web site. Another thing is - you should havr an enormous amount of free space. Maybe that's the reason for the error?

Comment: I have plenty of space in my hard disk. I am trying to avoid MSVC.

Comment: why? what is wrong with MSVC? Also, I think you will not be able to do that - AFAIR, this library is officially supported under MSVC only. There was a post from on the wx forum about PdfDocument couple of month ago...